# Search scope of NSMetadataQuery

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmetadataquery

Is there any way of excluding the /Users/username/Library (which is hidden by default) from the search scope of NSMetadataQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSMetadataQuery provides the feasibility for setting the search scope (setSearchScope) , better try out by setting the required search paths.